# Chrome Packaged App - using multiple HTML files

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Can a Chrome Packaged App contain more than a single HTML file?

I developed a packaged app in Chrome but I find that all the HTML needs to go in a single file (in DIVs) and I show/hide the DIVs based upon the requirement.

I tried using multiple HTML files but was unable to call one file from another.

Is there any way to use multiple HTML files in Chrome Packaged APP?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "call one file from another" ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem: "Calling one file from other" simply refers to invoking a file (say 2.html) on click of an anchor tag in currently active file (say 1.html).

Comment: Does it mean opening a new window loading the file ? Does it mean replace the current page in the current window ? Have you tried using an `iframe` ? BTW, you failed to tell us what you have tried and how it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options:

- open a new window ([chrome.app.window.create](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create)) and point it to the new content;
- fetch the new content using XMLHttpRequest and replace the current document's innerHTML:

```
    document.documentElement.innerHTML="test"
```

I would always go with the first option. If you don't need the previous content anymore, just close the old window.

Comment: From the question, I had the impression that the files are local, so XMLHttpRequest won't work. See my answer below.

Comment: What makes you think that XMLHttpRequest doesn't work for local content? That shouldn't be an issue (just tested here to make sure). Let me know if you are having issues.

Comment: can you tell me how you close the window @mangini I tried `window.close()` but it does not work

Comment: The appWindow object returned by chrome.app.window.create has a close() method. Use that instead of window.close().

Answer (score 0):

In one of your JavaScript files, add code to add an object element (new with HTML5) to the DOM that references the HTML file that you want included. (Haven't tried this, but it might work.)